# How to build an event listener during (or before??) a save action that determines whether a change is being executed on a given field

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

I am trying to update certain fields during a save, but only if one field is being changed, but I don't know how to go about doing that.

More info: if a user is making an edit on the 'is_activated' field in my model, then and only then should my function 'suspendToActive' be invoked; otherwise it should always be ignored.

Here's my current save action:

```
public function save(Doctrine_Connection $conn = null)
      {
        if ($this->isNew() && !$this->getExpiresAt())
        {
                ... // 
        }

        elseif ($this->getIsActivated()) // this is where I'm having trouble...
        {
            suspendToActive();
        }      

    return parent::save($conn);        
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are Event Listeners in Doctrine, so you should use your model's preUpdate() function and use the invokers data to check if a value was changed.

You will find detailed informations here : http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/event-listeners/pl#record-listeners

Comment: Thanks for the response.  That's actually where I've been looking for the answer, but since I'm a relative newb, I'm confused as to where the function should be placed and how to create the listener.

Comment: The function is inherited from the Doctrine_Record class, so you may overwrite it in your model.    <br/>`public function preUpdate(Doctrine_Event $event){ if($this->getIsActivated()){ suspendToActive(); }}`

Comment: I get this error when I try that: Declaration of Job::preUpdate() should be compatible with that of Doctrine_Record::preUpdate()

Comment: Okay, I got it working. I had it in the main class instead of the table class. Seems to be working now.

Comment: Ok, I have a followup question if you don't mind.  Apparently, this isn't what I needed after all.  It worked to the extent that it was invoked whenever a change was made to that field, but I need it to be more specific... I need it to only be invoked when the change is from 'true' to 'false' (it's a boolean field), and to not be invoked when a change is made from 'false' to 'true'.  Is that possible?

Comment: Well, for this you may check the value of your field in the preUpdate function against the current value stored in the database. `$dbval = Doctrine_Core::getTable("MyModel")->find($this->getId()); if(($dbval->getIsActivated() === true) AND ($this->getIsActivated() === false){ supendToActive(); }